# Conditional operator " ? : "

Tags: c, conditional-operator

I've done my programming exam in C yesterday. There was a question I could not answer, and even though I've studied today I can't come up with a solution.

So we have this:

```
int A= -1 , B= -2, C= -3, X=1;
X = B != C ? A=(~C) - A-- : ++C + (~A);
printf("A= %d  B= %d  C =%d  X=%d \n", A,B,C,X);
```

I know this operator functions if `X = B != C` is true then `A=(~C) - A--` is executed. If it's false, `++C + (~A)` is executed.

Can anyone tell me and explain what are the values of A, B, C and X in that `printf`?

NEW

This was included in a question that asks to do a "trace" to the whole program:

```
     #include <stdio.h>
            void main(){
            int A= -1 , B= -2, C= -3, X=1;

        X = B != C ? A=(~C) - A-- : ++C + (~A);
        printf("A= %d  B= %d  C =%d  X=%d \n", A,B,C,X);

if(~A){
        printf("\n out1\n");
        C= A | B
        printf("A= %d  B= %d  C =%d  X=%d \n", A,B,C,X);
        C= C <<1;}

if(A^B){
         printf("\n out2\n");
        C= B & A
        B += 2
        X= X>>1
        printf("A= %d  B= %d  C =%d  X=%d \n", A,B,C,X);
```

By the way can anyone tell me what does it mean those `if` conditions?

Comment: That's a horrible exam question, btw. But what else is new.

Comment: close, but that line doesn't check if ```X = B != C```, rather it checks if ```B != C``` then assigns either the left or right arguments of ```:``` to ```X```

Comment: Check this out: [C Language Operators](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-operators)

Comment: @David Ameixa  The statement has undefined behavior.

Comment: I bet UB wasn't one of the possible answers ;)

Comment: What was the exam's "correct" answer?

Comment: Can you please tell us the name of the institution giving such an exams so we can promote banning it from teaching programming?\

Comment: @EugeneSh.; hahahaaa. Lol, you nailed it.

Answer (score 8):

The statement

```
X = B != C ? A=(~C) - A-- : ++C + (~A);
```

is equivalent to

```
if(B != C)
    X = (A = (~C) - (A--));
else 
    X = ++C + (~A);
```

So, the expression `A = (~C) - (A--)` invokes undefined behavior. In this case nothing good can be expected.

That said, this is a faulty question and shouldn't be asked in an examination. Or it could be asked with multiple choice answers as long as one option states that *the code will invoke undefined behavior*.

Comment: With `B= -2, C= -3`, the `if(B != C)` is certainly true and execution proceeds to the bad boy `X = (A = (~C) - (A--));`.  Yet I am confident that even if the code was `if(B == C)` and the `X = (A = (~C) - (A--));` path was not taken, the code as a whole is still UB.  I am sure there is a post on that somewhere.

Comment: @chux: Unevaluated code isn't UB even if it would necessarily be UB if executed. The standard gives the [example](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note118) that `2 || 1 / 0` is a valid integer constant expression with value 1, and the `1 / 0` part doesn't make it UB.

Comment: @user2357112 Hmmm - agree about `2 || 1 / 0`.  I'll have to take time to find that post.

Answer (score 3):

This question should never be on an exam, because it contains undefined behavior.

Specifically, this assignment `A = (~C) - A--` modifies `A` twice - in the `--` compound assignment, and in the assignment itself. Since there is no [sequence point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point#Sequence_points_in_C_and_C.2B.2B) in between the two, the behavior is undefined.

**Note:** This does not mean that the program is not going to print anything. It would most definitely produce some output on most platforms. However, none of that matters, because C the program is invalid in its entirety: it can produce any output it chooses to, produce no output, or even crash.

Comment: @DeiDei The same way everyone else tells UB - by examining the code, and checking it against C language standard.

Comment: Just as a side question, is `A=A=5;` also UB? A is being assigned twice. (Although the same value)

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Yes, it is UB, because C99 standard considers writing the same value a modification: "Modify’’ includes the case where the new value being stored is the same as the previous value (Section 3.1, part 3).

Answer (score 0):

Why not to surprise your teacher with very detailed explanation of what is happening ;)

```
    ...
    mov     eax, dword ptr [rbp - 16]       ; get C
    xor     eax, -1                         ; negate C
    mov     ecx, dword ptr [rbp - 8]        ; get A
    mov     edx, ecx                        ; put A into edx
    add     edx, -1                         ; add -1 to edx => A--
    mov     dword ptr [rbp - 8], edx        ; store result inside A
    sub     eax, ecx                        ; substract from ~C what was the result of A--
    mov     dword ptr [rbp - 8], eax        ; store it inside variable A
    ...
```